# Mission: File security with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

How do I achieve this mission with AWS S3? When a user goes to access a file by clicking a hyperlink to it (a link to an object in our s3 bucket), our system should ask them to sign in if they're not already signed in. System will have a list of users from us that are authorized to view the file at that URL. For files uploaded by a customer, the authorized users will be:

- the customer
- all our salespeople who have an appointment with that customer
- our admin panel users

If a person visits the URL, and they are not one of the handful of people authorized by our system to view the file at that url, AWS should not serve the file.

**NB: our system in this context means our company's website.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a person visits the URL, and they are not one of the handful of people authorized by our system to view the file at that url, AWS should not serve the file.

Indeed there are several ways to achieve this feature. The first step is to prevent public access to the bucket (all requests need to be authenticated).

The simplest option is using the [presigned url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html). The application will generate a presigned url for the authenticated users for the S3 object giving the users temporary access to the S3 objects.

Another option is using a CDN (CloudFront) and a [signed access cookie](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html) (as in the previous answer)

Answer (score -2):

There are several ways to archive your requirement.
But with your condition, you cannot archive it with S3 alone, you still need Cloudfront to do it (please check [Using a Signed URL to Serve Private Content](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html).)

When users log in, you can check user's subscription to provide them a cookie, this cookie will automatically add to request to Cloudfront (Represent to your S3). Please note that you need to check how to create cookies to share between your website and CDN (cloudfront).

Comment: You do not need cloudfront. It is possible with cloudfront, but it is not necessary.